Need help in debugging request and response in PHP calling an API
I need some help to resolve below php code. not sure what am i missing. I am trying to call an API through POST and in response i'm getting credentials are invalid. The same thing i tried in postman getting a response correctly. But with below code i with same credentials i'm getting a response as invalid credentials.
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL); // Set to show all errors for debugging

            
// Database connection (using PDO for this example)


// Fetch API username and password from the apiusers table
try {
    $sql = 'SELECT username, password FROM apiusers WHERE BPD_ID = :BPD_ID';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':BPD_ID', $BPD_ID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $apiUsername = $user['username'];
    $apiPassword = $user['password'];
    
    // Display username and password in console
    echo "<script>console.log('Username: " . addslashes($apiUsername) . "');</script>";
    echo "<script>console.log('Password: " . addslashes($apiPassword) . "');</script>";
    
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Failed to fetch API user data: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

// Fetch data from the database
// Build the postData array
$postData = json_encode([
    "supplyType" => "O",
    "subSupplyType" => "8",
    "subSupplyDesc" => "DC",
    .........
    "vehicleType" => "R",
    "itemList" => $itemData
]);

// Output the request data to the console
echo "<pre>";
print_r($postData);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($itemData);
echo "</pre>";

Full Request:
{
    "supplyType": "O",
    "subSupplyType": "8",
    "subSupplyDesc": "DELIVERY CHALLAN",
    "docType": "CHL",
    "docNo": "DC242501",
    "docDate": "01/08/2024",
    "fromGstin": "29AAFCC9980M1ZR",
    "fromTrdName": "welton",
    "fromAddr1": "2ND CROSS NO 59  19  A",
    "fromAddr2": "GROUND FLOOR OSBORNE ROAD",
    "fromPlace": "FRAZER TOWN",
    "fromPincode": 560090,
    "actFromStateCode": 29,
    "fromStateCode": 29,
    "toGstin": "29AEKPV7203E1Z9",
    "toTrdName": "sthuthya",
    "toAddr1": "Shree Nilaya",
    "toAddr2": "Dasarahosahalli",
    "toPlace": "Beml Nagar",
    "toPincode": 560090,
    "actToStateCode": 29,
    "toStateCode": 29,
    "transactionType": 1,
    "otherValue": "0",
    "totalValue": 40000,
    "cgstValue": 0,
    "sgstValue": 0,
    "igstValue": 0,
    "cessValue": 0,
    "cessNonAdvolValue": 0,
    "totInvValue": 47200,
    "transporterId": "",
    "transporterName": "",
    "transDocNo": "",
    "transMode": "1",
    "transDistance": "100",
    "transDocDate": "",
    "vehicleNo": "PVC1234",
    "vehicleType": "R",
    "itemList": [
        {
            "productName": "MS & SCRAP",
            "productDesc": "SCRAP",
            "hsnCode": 7402,
            "quantity": 4,
            "qtyUnit": "BOX",
            "cgstRate": 9,
            "sgstRate": 9,
            "igstRate": 0,
            "cessRate": 0,
            "cessNonadvol": 0,
            "taxableAmount": 40000
        }
    ]
}

// cURL setup
$url = 'https://my.gstzen.in/~gstzen/a/ewbapi/generate/?username=' . rawurlencode($apiUsername) . '&password=' . rawurlencode($apiPassword);
$apiKey = 'de3a3a01-273a-4a81-8b75-13fe37f14d';
$gstin = '29AAFCC9980M1'; // Your GSTIN value
/* $gstin = $mainData['COMP_GSTIN']; // Your GSTIN value */


// Initialize cURL session
$ch = curl_init($url);

// Set cURL options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: API key ' . $apiKey,
    'gstin: ' . $gstin
]);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

// Execute cURL request and get the response
$response = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'cURL error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    exit;
}

curl_close($ch);

// Decode the JSON response
$responseData = json_decode($response, true);

if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    die('JSON decode error: ' . json_last_error_msg());
}


// Debugging the API response
echo "<script>console.log('API Response: " . addslashes(json_encode($responseData)) . "');</script>";

// Check for authentication errors
if (isset($responseData['status']) && $responseData['status'] === 'error' && isset($responseData['message'])) {
    die('API error: ' . $responseData['message']);
}

// Insert data into the database 



    $pdo->commit();
    echo 'Data inserted successfully';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $pdo->rollBack();
    echo 'Failed to insert data: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>

response from API call:
console.log('API Response: {\\"status\\":0,\\"message\\":\\"The user credentials provided in the request are invalid.\\"}');

Postman response  is attached as image

Request JSON from Postman
{
    "supplyType": "O",
    "subSupplyType": "8",
    "subSupplyDesc": "DELIVERY CHALLAN",
    "docType": "CHL",
    "docNo": "DC242501",
    "docDate": "01/08/2024",
    "fromGstin": "29AAFCC9980M1ZR",
    "fromTrdName": "welton",
    "fromAddr1": "2ND CROSS NO 59  19  A",
    "fromAddr2": "GROUND FLOOR OSBORNE ROAD",
    "fromPlace": "FRAZER TOWN",
    "fromPincode": 560090,
    "actFromStateCode": 29,
    "fromStateCode": 29,
    "toGstin": "29AEKPV7203E1Z9",
    "toTrdName": "sthuthya",
    "toAddr1": "Shree Nilaya",
    "toAddr2": "Dasarahosahalli",
    "toPlace": "Beml Nagar",
    "toPincode": 560090,
    "actToStateCode": 29,
    "toStateCode": 29,
    "transactionType": 1,
    "otherValue": "0",
    "totalValue": 40000,
    "cgstValue": 0,
    "sgstValue": 0,
    "igstValue": 0,
    "cessValue": 0,
    "cessNonAdvolValue": 0,
    "totInvValue": 47200,
    "transporterId": "",
    "transporterName": "",
    "transDocNo": "",
    "transMode": "1",
    "transDistance": "100",
    "transDocDate": "",
    "vehicleNo": "PVC1234",
    "vehicleType": "R",
    "itemList": [
        {
            "productName": "MS & SCRAP",
            "productDesc": "SCRAP",
            "hsnCode": 7402,
            "quantity": 4,
            "qtyUnit": "BOX",
            "cgstRate": 9,
            "sgstRate": 9,
            "igstRate": 0,
            "cessRate": 0,
            "cessNonadvol": 0,
            "taxableAmount": 40000
        }
    ]
}

Reponse JSON from Postman
{
    "status": 1,
    "uuid": "cc1e4f5d-43ca-4373-9fd4-6e059fb6716a",
    "message": "EWB Generated",
    "alert": "",
    "validUpto": "06/08/2024 11:59:00 PM",
    "ewayBillNo": 171010516152,
    "ewayBillDate": "05/08/2024 07:16:00 PM",
    "EWayBillPdfUrl": "/~fnsjdjszvw/a/eway-bill/cc1e4f5d-43ca-4373-9fd4-6e059fb6716a/ewb/.pdf/",
    "EWayBillQrCodeUrl": "/~fnsjdjszvw/a/ewaybill/cc1e4f5d-43ca-4373-9fd4-6e059fb6716a/qr-code/",
    "Distance": "100"
}


We can't see the headers you've set in postman. Presumably something about them is different than your curl version - either the headers used, or the contents - since the authentication is set in the headers rather than the body.

P.s. postman can generate php code for you automatically...have you tried using that?

Code from postman solved the issue. Thanks you!

Code from postman resolved the issue.

Please read [answer]. This will be no use to anyone in future unless you share the relevant code and information you used to solve the problem. You can [edit] your answer. Please also take the [tour] to ensure you understand how Stackoverflow works and what it's for. We're not just a regular discussion forum. Thanks.
